# Learning AJAX: The use of pushState()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm learning AJAX to make this effect:

- Change the content and URL via AJAX so the music plays seamless along the website.

You can see what I've got so far in the following link, The JavaScript seems working well changing the URL without reloading the page, but the content does not change.

This is the link: [/p/test1.html](http://www.revistadrive.com/p/test1.html)

This is the Code used:

```js
$(function() {
   $('nav a').click(function(e) {
    $("#loading").show();
    href = $(this).attr("href");
    
    loadContent(href);
    
    // HISTORY.PUSHSTATE
    history.pushState('', 'New URL: '+href, href);
    e.preventDefault();
    
    
   });
   
   // THIS EVENT MAKES SURE THAT THE BACK/FORWARD BUTTONS WORK AS WELL
   window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    $("#loading").show();
    console.log("pathname: "+location.pathname);
    loadContent(location.pathname);
   };

  });
 
  function loadContent(url){
   // USES JQUERY TO LOAD THE CONTENT
   $.getJSON("content.php", {cid: url, format: 'json'}, function(json) {
     // THIS LOOP PUTS ALL THE CONTENT INTO THE RIGHT PLACES
     $.each(json, function(key, value){
      $(key).html(value);
     });
     $("#loading").hide();
    });
   
   // THESE TWO LINES JUST MAKE SURE THAT THE NAV BAR REFLECTS THE CURRENT URL
   $('li').removeClass('current');
   $('a[href="'+url+'"]').parent().addClass('current');
   
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://html5.gingerhost.com/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/D8eDDJmrM_0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<div id="content">
  <div id="loading"></div>
        <nav>
   
            <ul id="menu" class="clearfix"> 
                <li class="current"><a href="/p/test1.html">PAGE 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/p/test2.html">PAGE 2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <br class="clear" />
        </nav>
   
    
    <div id="main" class="grid_8 alpha">
    
        <article class="post">
        
            <h1>A different content 2</h1>
            
   <div id="articletext">
    <p>click any link to change this content</p>            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>  
            
          
        
        </article> 
    
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help! I really need this!

Comment: Any error messages in the console? Is the success method firing? Is the code going into the each? Is it finding the elements? console.log and break points are your friend.

Comment: I don't even know how to use that, where can I see that?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/ Every modern day browser has one.

Comment: seems like its `Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)` issue  kindly refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS